# Unexpected Output of .match() and regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using `match()` and `regex` to receive an array of all occurrences of "Name". Name can be any string and is just a placeholder for this example.

As you can see in the first two iterations I receive the expected output. The third iteration however ignores the first `\n` and also outputs the previous line.

Any ideas why this happens?

```js
$("#shortDescTextarea").on('keyup', function() {
  var currentVal = $(this).val();
  var allItemNames = currentVal.match(/\n[^:]+:/g);

  console.log(allItemNames);

});
```

```css
textarea{height:250px;width:500px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="shortDescTextarea" class="form-control">|H|Header|/H|
Name: Value
Name: Value
|H|Header|/H|
Name:
</textarea>
```

Comment: you need to capture the values of the names or what?

Comment: looking at your 1st and 2nd matches, i think this is what you need: `\n[^:\n]+:` i.e, just add a `\n` in the brackets

Comment: or a simpler one `\n.+:`, note: `.` matches any character (except for line terminators)

Comment: Sorry, I must have skipped something as I was reading,. I see what you are saying now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could fix this is adding the `\n` inside the brackets, like this:

> currentVal.match(/\n[^:\n]+:/g);

Note that this `/\n[^:]+:/g` will capture all characters between a `\n` and `:` that do not include a `:` char, so this pattern `\n|H|Header|/H|\nName:` will be captured.

**Example:**

```js
$("#shortDescTextarea").on('keyup', function()
{
    var currentVal = $(this).val();
    var allItemNames = currentVal.match(/\n[^:\n]+:/g);
    console.log(allItemNames);
});
```

```css
textarea{height:250px;width:500px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="shortDescTextarea" class="form-control">|H|Header|/H|
Name: Value
Name: Value
|H|Header|/H|
Name:
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not match on `\n`, as it is not guaranteed to be there (e.g. if `Name:...` happens to be the first line of your text). Instead, use the `m` (multiline) flag, where `^` matches start of the line, however it comes to be. Similarly, you can use `?` "non-greedy" modifier to make sure you don't cross over a colon, which makes it easy to use `.`, which doesn't match newlines, avoiding having to explicitly guard against them. Final result:

```
/^.*?:/gm
```

To capture both pre-colon and post-colon value:

```js
let str = `
Name: Foo
Name: Bar
Header stuff I don't understand
Name: Quux
`;
let re = /^(.*?):\s*(.*)$/gm
results = [];
while (m = re.exec(str)) {
  results.push([m[1], m[2]]);
}
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternativ and the explanation. Could you also give an example where I get the string from `:` to the end of the line?